# How do I scrape data from the <span> tag, if it is without 'id' or 'class', using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the data from within the  tag. The issue is, it has no 'id' or 'class', so how can I get the data inside this tag?

```
<span>  
  <span>2 in Amazon Launchpad (<a href="/-/en/gp/bestsellers/boost/ref=pd_zg_ts_boost">See Top 100 in Amazon Launchpad</a>)</span> 
<br> 
  <span>1 in <a href="/-/en/gp/bestsellers/drugstore/2860173031/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_drugstore">Forehead Thermometers</a></span> 
<br>  
  <span>1 in <a href="/-/en/gp/bestsellers/boost/22130220031/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_boost">Amazon Launchpad Coupons</a></span> 
<br> 
</span>
```

Above is the data I need to scrape.

I tried using the below line of code, but it didn't worked. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
soup.find("span", class_=False, id=False)
```

Comment: I see no `<p>` tag in the HTML you've posted. Confirm the url of the page you're scraping, as well as what date are you after, and in what format. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Look at your HTML layout and detect the closest tag for your `<span>` (which has class or id) and then use the power of [CSS Selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors).

For proper example, provide HTML snippet where `<snap>` is located with some other tags around.

Comment: Okay got it, will try the same way. Thanks a lot for answering.

Comment: In addition to above suggestion, once you get the nearest parent tag containing your span tag, you can use the "contents" property to get the array of children and then you can manually calculate and find index of your span in the array.